# React component doesn't update while testing with react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am struggling to understand why this component doesn't update after I click on it with userEvent. I have a search bar, when focused === true, it expands, and has another field "Move in". This is my test that doesn't work and I don't get the search bar expanded after clicking.

```
describe("Searchbar tests", () => {
  let SearchBar = (
    <DesktopSearch
      wrapper={wrap}
      handleKeyDown={jest.fn()}
      handleChange={jest.fn()}
      availability={undefined}
    />
  );

  it("should have move in once focused", async () => {
    render(SearchBar);
    const searchDiv = await screen.findByTestId("search-location");
    await userEvent.click(searchDiv);
    expect(screen.getByText("Move in")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

screen.debug()

```
  <body>
      <div>
        <div
          class="sc-ksdxgE cXdeLl"
        >
          <div
            class="sc-hBUSln bQqsgK"
            data-testid="search-location"
          >
            <span
              style="width: 0px; opacity: 0;"
            >
              Search
            </span>
            <div>
              <span
                style="line-height: 0.5;"
              >
                Location
              </span>
              <input
                class="sc-fotOHu bfsfMe"
                value=""
              />
            </div>
            <div
              class="sc-fFeiMQ htNsUj"
              style="width: 6.49676%;"
            />
          </div>
          <svg
            class="sc-kfPuZi kGORHg"
            fill="currentColor"
            height="20"
            stroke="currentColor"
            stroke-width="0"
            viewBox="0 0 16 16"
            width="20"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
            <title>
              Search
            </title>
            <path
              d="M15.7 13.3l-3.81-3.83A5.93 5.93 0 0 0 13 6c0-3.31-2.69-6-6-6S1 2.69 1 6s2.69 6 6 6c1.3 0 2.48-.41 3.47-1.11l3.83 3.81c.19.2.45.3.7.3.25 0 .52-.09.7-.3a.996.996 0 0 0 0-1.41v.01zM7 10.7c-2.59 0-4.7-2.11-4.7-4.7 0-2.59 2.11-4.7 4.7-4.7 2.59 0 4.7 2.11 4.7 4.7 0 2.59-2.11 4.7-4.7 4.7z"
              fill-rule="evenodd"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Minimal example:

```
    import { SearchBarContext } from "context";
import { AnimatePresence, AnimateSharedLayout, motion } from "framer-motion";
import { ReactElement, useContext } from "react";
import { DeviceSearchProps } from ".";
import {
  AutocompleteContainer,
  SearchAvailability,
  SearchDate,
  SearchIcon,
  SearchInput,
  SearchLocation,
  SearchStyle,
} from "./desktopStyles";

    export default function DesktopSearch({
      className,
      wrapper,
      handleKeyDown: _handleKeyDown,
      handleChange: _handleChange,
      availability,
    }: DeviceSearchProps): ReactElement {
      const { focus, focused } = useContext(SearchBarContext);
      // [focused, setFocused] = useState(false),
      //focus = () => setFocused(true),
    
      return (
        <SearchStyle className={className} ref={wrapper}>
          <AnimateSharedLayout>
            <SearchLocation onClick={focus} layout>
              <AnimatePresence>
                <motion.span
                  initial={{ width: "0px" }}
                  animate={{
                    width: focused ? "0px" : "auto",
                    opacity: focused ? 0 : 1,
                  }}
                  transition={{ duration: 0.5, type: "string", delay: 0.2 }}
                >
                  Search
                </motion.span>
              </AnimatePresence>
              <div>
                <span style={{ lineHeight: 0.5 }}>Location</span>
                <SearchInput isFocused={focused} />
              </div>
              <AutocompleteContainer
                animate={{ width: focused ? "110%" : "90%" }}
                transition={{ duration: 0.2, type: "string" }}
              ></AutocompleteContainer>
            </SearchLocation>
    
            {focused && (
              <>
                <SearchDate>
                  <SearchAvailability
                    initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                    exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
                  >
                    {availability ? (
                      availability.toLocaleDateString("en-GB")
                    ) : false ? (
                      <>__ __ __</>
                    ) : (
                      "Move in"
                    )}
                  </SearchAvailability>
                </SearchDate>
              </>
            )}
            <SearchIcon size={20} />
          </AnimateSharedLayout>
        </SearchStyle>
      );

}
```

Comment: Could you please call [screen.debug()](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#screendebug) after clicking on the element and attach the result to your question?

Comment: Without a [mre] including a minimal component, it's very hard to say.

Comment: I don't think `<div />` element can be focused without specifying [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) to it. Or, as an alternative, you can assign `data-testid="search-location"` attribute to `input` element within the "search location" block

Comment: Hey! Did you try to know is when doing the userEvent is really focused? Check this https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-events/#focusblur

Comment: Hey, @S.Marx I just tried it, and it doesn't work, unfortunately. Thank you, tho

Comment: How do you handle the focus === true?

Comment: I haven't tested it but you are testing the initial render in your test. Not the one after the button is click. You might have to wait for the text to be in the document with something like 
`await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByText("Move in")).toBeInTheDocument();
  });`

Comment: Hi @KevinAmiranoff I thought about it, and waited for it  but I guess that's not the issue

Comment: @illyria, I may also assume that it doesn't work with context, because the context doesn't exist when you render the component with react testing library. Try to add a [wrapper](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#wrapper) to the render function to wrap the component by the context - `render(SearchBar, {wrapper: SearchBarContext.Provider})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in this code is that the context doesn't exist when you render the component with react testing library. Try to add a [wrapper](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#wrapper) to the render function to wrap the component by the context

```
const WithContextProviders = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <SearchBarContext.Provder {...providersPropsIfNeeded}>
      {children}
    </SearchBarContext.Provder>
  );
};

it("should have move in once focused", async () => {
  render(SearchBar, { wrapper: WithContextProviders });
  const searchDiv = await screen.findByTestId("search-location");
  await userEvent.click(searchDiv);
  expect(screen.getByText("Move in")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried both, and it still doesn't work. I get the same screen.debug()

Comment: Can you also attach the implementation of the component so we can reproduce this problem?

Comment: The component is quite big, and takes props from other components, and uses useContext. I am not sure I can post all you'd need

Comment: You can post a minimal example that reproduces the same problem

Comment: I edited again the main post with it

Comment: Edited the answer according to the new details

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know how you handle the `focus === true` I've created a little example that maybe helps you:

I handle if is focused or not with a useState by default false and then when, in that case the button, is clicked changes to true *Move in* is displayed

```
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);

  const handleFocus = () => {
    setIsFocus(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleFocus}>Display text when clicked</button>
      {isFocus ? <p>Move in</p> : ""}
    </>
  );
}  
export default App;
```

And this is the test, that passes:

```
test("focus should render", async () => {
  render(<App />);

  expect(screen.queryByText(/Move in/i)).not.toBeInTheDocument();

  fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Display text when clicked/i));
  expect(screen.getByText(/Move in/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @S.Marx, I updated the question with the component, but either way, focus is just setFocused(true). I tried your code, but it doesn't work

Comment: How do you handle when is focused or not in your code?

Comment: it's just a usestate, defaulted to false, when I click it becomes true

Comment: How weird, it should work. Or add some moe code sho we can see

Comment: I've made some brief changes and the pass test screenshot, give it a try

Comment: Still nothing. The only thing I can think of is that focus and focused come from useContext, or I have no idea. Thank you though

Comment: Maybe you should `jest.fn()` the function thats sets focus to true

Comment: The issue apparently is the useContext. I changed focus and focused with local states there and it works. I guess I need to understand how to make it work with useContext. Thank you!